# Функция из значений словаря, выводит список разбивая по символам

Tags: python, django

```
icecream_db = [
{
'name': 'Золотое мороженое',
'description': ('Шарики таитянского ванильного мороженого'),
},
{
'name': 'Готическое мороженое',
'description': ('Чёрное мороженое в чёрном вафельном рожке.'),
},
{
'name': 'Мороженое паста карбонара',
'description': ('Порция макарон под тёмным соусом. ),
},]


def icecream_list(request):
icecreams = []
for i in range(len(icecream_db)):
    icecreams += f'{icecream_db[i]["name"]} :: ' 
return HttpResponse(f'Cписок сортов мороженого: {icecreams}')
```

Выводит Cписок сортов мороженого: ['З', 'о', 'л', 'о', 'т', 'о', 'е', ' ', 'м', 'о', 'р', 'о', 'ж', 'е', 'н', 'о', 'е', ' ', ':', ':', ' ', 'Г', 'о', 'т', 'и', 'ч', 'е', 'с', 'к', 'о', 'е', ' ', 'м', 'о', 'р', 'о', 'ж', 'е', 'н', 'о', 'е', ' ', ':', ':', ' ...

Функция из значений словаря, выводит список разбивая по символам, что я не так делаю?
Должен выводить так:

> Золотое мороженное :: Готическое мороженное :: Мороженое паста карбонара

Comment: исправь код, этот код нерабочий. И что такое HttpResponse и зачем оно тут надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
icecreams = []
for i in range(len(icecream_db)):
    icecreams += f'{icecream_db[i]["name"]} :: '
```

на

```
icecreams = ' :: '.join(item['name'] for item in icecream_db)
```

Answer (score 0):

Отбросил код с request-ами, в упрощенном виде получается примерно так:

```py
icecream_db = [
{
'name': 'Золотое мороженое',
'description': ('Шарики таитянского ванильного мороженого'),
},
{
'name': 'Готическое мороженое',
'description': ('Чёрное мороженое в чёрном вафельном рожке.'),
},
{
'name': 'Мороженое паста карбонара',
'description': ('Порция макарон под тёмным соусом.' ),
},
]

ice = []
for i in icecream_db:
    ice.append(i['name'] + " :: ") 
print(*ice)
```

насколько Вам нужны разделители в виде ::?

Answer (score 0):

замените icecreams = [] на icecreams = ''

Comment: Советую давать более развернутые ответы